# Export everything from Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to export everything (sites, dashboard, users, groups ecc...) is under my Alfresco ed import all to another Alfresco installation.

I discovered this usefull tool https://github.com/atolcd/alfresco-share-import-export but seems to me that it is good to create an .acp of a site for example but it's not enought for others stuff expecially users.

Please, what's an easy way to export everything from Alfresco ? And then how to import ? Thank you.

I used this Pynthon scripts github.com/wabson/share-import-export but no way an error on the python script execution : C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Nuova cartella>python export-users.py file.json --username=xxx --password=xxx --url=localhost:8080/share/page/site/xxx/dashboard File "export-users.py", line 5  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have Alfresco 5.1 and Pynthon 2.7.12

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfAwX.png)

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/wabson/share-import-export

Comment: Thanks ! I did what you said but it gives me an error on the python script execution : C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Nuova cartella>python export-users.py file.json --username=xxx --password=xxx --url=http://localhost:8080/share/page/site/xxx/dashboard

  File "export-users.py", line 5
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please update you question with these new informations.

Answer (score 1):

Your url param is incorrect. Use the below one.

```
python export-users.py file.json --username=admin --password=admin --url=http://localhost:8080/share
```

This should work for you.

The Share URL should be, `http://<IP or systemname>:<portnumber/share`, but you've mentioned the one site dashboard url. Please change that.

Comment: Thank you. I executed your command python export-users.py file.json --username=myusername --password=mypassword --url=http://localhost:8080/share but the error is the same of before like a said

Comment: Can you add debug (-d) param and share further information ?

Comment: First of all I downloaded the Python script from here https://github.com/wabson/share-import-export/tree/master/shareclient

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alfresco OOTB replication service and replicate all the data from one alfresco instance to second one.